# What should be the Firestore security settings for Android app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I just created my first `Android` app in `Kotlin` with `FIrestore` as the database and I used Phone Authentication as well. When I created the database, I used Test Mode and now I want to upload my app to Google Play so that the public can start using my app. What should be the security settings for the Firestore that I should consider changing? Please give some advice on this.

Currently, this is what is under the Rules tab.

```
    rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 8, 29);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you want the rules to be. If you could share a screenshot of your collections and explain who could access those collections and documents then there is a higher chance of someone able to help you with it.

Comment: Only a certain collection should not be accessed by all users (Say, Collection A, B and C). Some collections (Collection Y and Z) can be used by certain users. But, how can we define that? Some Collections (Collection P and Q) can be accessed by everyone who has logged in using Phone Auth. Users who have not signed in should not have any access.

Comment: If you can define who are those "certain users" it'll be easier for me to explain.

Comment: I do not know how is that done, is that done using his `uid`?

Comment: What I meant was, how are you going to differentiate between those users? Is it UIDs, or custom claims or something?

Comment: It will be UID if there is no issue doing so.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid but as a newbie, I would like to know this. Is there any issue if I allow access to everyone who has signed in (using Phone Auth) in the Firestore but does not give access to the user interface of the app to certain users that can add, delete, update, modify the data?

Comment: Are you saying something like allow reads and writes from security rules and just prevent users from using the UI in your app? You should not do that. The conditional rendering of UI  can be changed. Your security rules should be valid to protect your app.

Comment: OK, I will try your answer. It's my first time doing this. :)

Comment: Security rules are part of your application logic. Asking "what should my security rules be?" is essentially the same as asking "what should my code be? It all depends on what your app is about. I recommend starting with https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started and posting back with a more concrete question once you become stuck in a more specific spot.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Sure, I will do that. There was some serious issue with my project and Firestore. As I changed the Firebase account. That's why I couldn't try this. But, I do remember this and I will get back and accept the answer as soon as I implement this rule, I will definitely do that. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand from the example in comments, you have 7 collections (example) A, B, C, P, Q, Y and Z.

| Collection | Can be accessed by |
| --- | --- |
| A, B, C | Certain users |
| P, Q | Users authenticated by Phone auth |
| Y, Z | Certain users |

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /A/{docId} {
      allow read, write: if isCertainUser();
    }
    // Same rule for B and C

    match /P/{docId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider == "phone";
    }
    // Same rule for Q
    // Checks if user is logged in by Phone auth

    match /Y/{docId} {
      allow read, write: if isCertainUser();
    }
    // Same rule for Z
  }
}
```

You would have to write a function `isCertainUser` for the rule to work. Now there are multiple ways you can specify a user to have access. For example, you could add an admin [custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) or store documents of users who can access the collection in a separate collection and check if the document of user who is requesting data is present in that whitelisted collection.

```js
match /A/{docId} {
  allow read: if request.auth != null && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/whitelisted/$(request.auth.uid));
}
```

This rule will allow users to read data in collection A only if a document with the user's UID as document key exists in the collection "whitelisted".

References:

[Writing conditions for Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication)

[Interface for request.auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth)